# App parando ao usar a Location API

Tags: java, android, google-maps-android-api-2, google-api, google-location-api

Esse código serviria para quando o usuário apertasse um botão, sua latitude e longitude fossem encontradas para posteriormente serem enviadas para um servidor. Mas o app crasha quando inicia, lembrando que peguei esse código de  um post aqui no SOpt.

O erro que dá é esse:

```
Process: com.example.elvisriboli.locationapi, PID: 13138
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.elvisriboli.locationapi/com.example.elvisriboli.locationapi.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: blockingConnect must not be called on the UI thread
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2201)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2250)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:141)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1213)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5072)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: blockingConnect must not be called on the UI thread
    at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzx.zza(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzj.blockingConnect(Unknown Source)
    at com.example.elvisriboli.locationapi.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:46)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5249)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2165)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2250)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:141)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1213)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5072)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

***MEU CÓDIGO***

**Manifest**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

**Main Activity**

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

    Button btLocalizacao;
    double lat, longi;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



        btLocalizacao = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btLocalizacao);

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
        mGoogleApiClient.blockingConnect();

        btLocalizacao.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (GetLocalization(MainActivity.this)) {
                    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        // TODO: Consider calling
                        return;
                    }
                    Location location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
                    if (location != null) {
                        lat = location.getLatitude();
                         longi =   location.getLongitude();
                    } else {
                        showSettingsAlert();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }

    public boolean GetLocalization(Context context) {
        int REQUEST_PERMISSION_LOCALIZATION = 221;
        boolean res = true;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // TODO: Consider calling
                res = false;
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) context, new String[]{
                                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                        REQUEST_PERMISSION_LOCALIZATION);

            }
        }
        return res;
    }

    public void showSettingsAlert(){
        android.app.AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new android.app.AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);

        // Titulo do dialogo
        alertDialog.setTitle("GPS");

        // Mensagem do dialogo
        alertDialog.setMessage("GPS não está habilitado. Deseja configurar?");

        // On pressing Settings button
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Configurar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                MainActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        // on pressing cancel button
        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancelar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

        // visualizacao do dialogo
        alertDialog.show();
    }
}
```

**Gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.elvisriboli.locationapi"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.4.0'
}
```

Answer (score 2):

O erro indicado é:
**blockingConnect não deve ser chamado na activity principal**

Faça o seguinte, remova essas linhas do seu onCreate:

```
 mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
        .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
        .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
        .addApi(LocationServices.API)
        .build();
mGoogleApiClient.blockingConnect();
```

Adicione em forma de método, fora do onCreate:

```
protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
}
```

Dentro do seu onCreate, você deixa somente essas duas linhas, que serão responsáveis por conectar com o ApiClient e chamar o método que vc adicionou fora do onCreate:

```
buildGoogleApiClient();
mGoogleApiClient.connect();
```

Answer (score 0):

O método [blockingConnect()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient.html#blockingConnect()) só pode ser utilizada num *thread* que não seja a *UI thread*.
Poderá usá-lo por exemplo no método `onExecute()` duma *AsyncTask*.

No entanto o recomendado é usar o método [connect()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient.html#connect()) e lidar com o resultado da conexão nos métodos das interfaces `ConnectionCallbacks` e `OnConnectionFailedListener`, a implementar pela sua *activity*.

Veja na [documentação](https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html?hl=pt-br) um exemplo de como fazê-lo.

Basicamente é construir o *GoogleApiClient* no método `oncreate()`

```
 mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
        .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
        .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
        .addApi(LocationServices.API)
        .build();
```

Chamar o método `connect()` no método `onStart()`

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    super.onStart();
}
```

Chamar o `disconnect()` no `onStop()`

```
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    super.onStop();
}
```

Implementar o método `onConnected()`, que será chamado quando a conexão for estabelecida.
**Nota:** Se a targetApi for 23 ou superior terá de verificar se tem a permissão em tempo de execução.

```
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {

    // Agora que a conexão foi estabelecida pode utilizar o LocationServices para,
    // por exemplo, obter a última localização do dispositivo

    //Nota: Se a targetApi for 23 ou superior terá de verificar se tem a permissão em tempo de execução.
    mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(
            mGoogleApiClient);
    ...
    ...

}
```